# Check which file executed in a directory C#

Tags: c#

I have a directory that contains a few executable files.

- app1.exe
- app2.exe
- app3.exe

I want to watch the directory continuously and when an executable runs, I need to print the file name of the executable. As an example, if app1.exe is executed then print `app1.exe`.

Comment: suggestion: **try something**. research. experiment. ask colleagues. show some effort. ask on stackoverflow as **last** step, not as first. (also: read about the tags you're using, and think if they are really relevant to your question. because `visual-studio` is _not at all_)

Comment: I suggest using a WMI ManagementEventWatcher to detect processes being started as in [this example](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/System.Management/ManagementEventWatcher/WaitForNextEvent/php-managementeventwatcher-waitfornextevent-method-examples.html)

Comment: @Krythic totally agree with you. This is how every newcomer act on the platform. I also used to ask this type of question.  But because of such comments only thing that happened is I was afraid and demotivated to ask questions. Yes, these types of questions are not good. It's better to research first. But at the same time that is not the way to answer them. It's not helping.

Comment: Krythic
@hackerbuddy
Huge respect for you guys...  i almost lost hopes and motivation. and yes the same thing happened to me after the reading the first comment. i was going to delete my question but you guys motivated me. So thanks alot for the help i will research about the WMI ManagementEventWatcher will also share the code after solving the problem.

Comment: @AdeelYousafzai Wish you luck, my dude. And once more, i apologize for the behavior of some members of this website. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use `FileSystemWatcher`. But in Windows 7 and later versions, you have to enable updating the Last access time.

[See this](https://superuser.com/questions/251263/the-last-access-date-is-not-changed-even-after-reading-the-file-on-windows-7)

You can use following application to get a notification.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Watcher
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run(args[0]);
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private static void Run(string directory)
    {
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
        {
            watcher.Path = directory;

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess;

            watcher.Filter = "*.exe";

            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;

            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) =>
        Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");

}
```

Resource - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0

Comment: and Dharman  i tried this one but the problem is there is no event hanlder for Last Access i think some custom event handler will work. Thank you

Comment: OnChange is handling the Last Access. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onchanged?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: This solution worked for me the only thing you have to do is. Run this command in the the  cmd and restart your system. after restart the above code will work like charm.

fsutil behavior set DisableLastAccess 0

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to check a directory continuously which contains executable files

[`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0)

> When a exe file runs i want to detect the file name

You can query running processes with [`Process.GetProcesses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=net-5.0), and for each process you have access to (permissions matter a lot), you have [`Process.MainModule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule?view=net-5.0) to get access to the "main" executable part of that process. From there you have [`Process.FileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processmodule.filename?view=net-5.0) to get the file path of the process.

Just make sure your process is 64-bit, or you'll need to resort to P/Invoke instead.

Comment: Thank You i will try and let you know. I think it will work.

Comment: Should FileSystemWatcher triggered by the Last Access Time here? (When executable file runs)

Comment: Depends what his reasoning is. If all he wants is to get the file path of a certain running process, there's no need for a file system watcher at all.

Comment: Yes, But I guess he wants to get a notification of the file name of the executable when an executable is run. Like if app.exe is executed print `app.exe`

Comment: @hackerbuddy Yes hackerbuddy is right just wanted to print the app name which executed. i will try both FileSystemWatch  i'm familiar with it but i didn't new that it had LastAccess function too.